# Setting up varnish in docker, nginx, php-fpm

Tags: php, docker, nginx, varnish

I need all api.test.local/app/pub requests to work through varnish.
I have my own docker container named fpm, in which php-fpm and nginx are running, and I want to put varnish there

default.vcl

```
vcl 4.1;
```

```
backend default {.host = "api.test.local";.port = "80";}
```

```
sub vcl_recv {if (req.url ~ "^/app/pub") {set req.backend_hint = default;}}
```

```
sub vcl_backend_response {if (bereq.url ~ "^/app/pub") {set beresp.ttl = 5m;}}
```

nginx.conf

```
server { include settings/shared/listen_80.conf;
root /projects/test/server/web;

index dev.php;
charset utf-8;

server_name test.local start.test.local api.test.local admin.test.local back.test.local backoffice.test.local web1.test.local web.test.local wv.test.local apimanager.test.local apiservice.test.local;
add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM $current_origin" always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers'    'Api-Session' always;

include settings/server/api-cors-headers.conf;

if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    return 204;
}
location /app/pub {
    proxy_pass http://fpm:6081;
}
include settings/server/root_location.conf;
include settings/shared/internal_php_location.conf;}
```

root_location.conf

`location / { try_files $uri /dev.php$uri?$args; }`

I get an error
`<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: You're putting too many things together: first of all, setup the nginx+php side so that you can succesfully navigate the application. Once that's done, add Varnish in front of it, with no rules / configurations, you should still be able to navigate it (there's a 2 minute default cache IIRC); next, add your custom VCL. If at any time you get errors, inspect [its logs](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/7.4/reference/index.html#logging-and-monitoring).